# calling a url with reverse with query string during unit testing

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have this URL that i want to test:

`urlpatterns = [ path('produce<str:code>', ProduceSpreadSheet.as_view(), name="produce" ), ]`

my test is:

```
class ProduceSpreadSheetTest(TestCase):

    
    def setUp(self):
        self.code = "abcd"
        
    def test_valid_token(self):
        url = reverse('produce', query_kwargs={'code': self.code})
        
        response = client.get(url)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I get the error:

TypeError: reverse() got an unexpected keyword argument 'query_kwargs'

when I change query_kwargs to kwargs: I get the error:

```
  TypeError: get() got an unexpected keyword argument 'code'
```

The method to be tested is:

```
class ProduceSpreadSheet(APIView):

   def get(self, request):

        code = request.query_params.get('code',None)
        // continue
```

I want to call it with

```
     .../produce?code=abcd
```

query_kwargs and kwargs and reverse('produce') + 'code=code'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `reverse` it is just `kwargs`, not `query_kwargs`:

```
class ProduceSpreadSheetTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.code = 'abcd'

    def test_valid_token(self):
        url = reverse('produce', kwargs={'code': self.code})

        response = self.client.get(url)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```